# Browse method API calls not matching Foursquare venue results

Tags: ios, api, foursquare

There are always extra venues in my data that are not real venues but Foursquare’s data does not show them. Why does using browse method for searching venues in the API on my app include a bunch of crappy data that is not included in Foursquare’s app?

How can I adjust my call to get the same set of clean(-er) data as Foursquare’s?  Are they limiting it based on a certain parameter that ensures that the venue was validated?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) are the docs for the venues/search endpoint. You will see the `intent` parameter is used to filter the results, based on the intent of the search. The Foursquare app uses intent="checkin" when searching for venues to check in to.

You can also use [venues/explore](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore), which is the endpoint the Foursquare app uses to recommend venues in Explore.